# limit bounty range

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, bounty

How could it be that a [user](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1172/l?tab=bounties) with reputation of 100 started 3 bounties 500 points each. Shouldn't the system check users reputation and bound his bounty range respectively?

Comment: Tagging [meta-tag:status-bydesign] in light of the answer which is AFAICT correct.

Comment: @msh210 what about [this user](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1479/rachav?tab=reputation) who isn't even registered? Looks like this user gave a +50 bounty after gaining only +30 rep. although perhaps i'm reading the info incorrectly.

Comment: @ه ه it shows one time for all upvotes on a post (thelatest time, I guess); he actually got some of the rep earlier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you issue a bounty, you give up the reputation that you already have - you don't give it up later. In this case, the user gave up about 1490 rep that [he already had in bounties](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1172/l?tab=reputation&sort=graph) & is left with 100 rep.