# Need you have reputation to offer a bounty?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [limit bounty range](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/924/limit-bounty-range)

I saw the following text after a [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14303/lifnei-iver-in-public-policy-business), "This question has an open bounty worth +300 reputation from l ' ending in 3 days." I checked the identity of l '. S/he only has reputation of 34. Shouldn't the system be programmed to avoid this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do. When you offer a bounty, the amount of rep is immediately deducted from your current reputation, so what you see now in l's profile is what is left after he offered the bounty.

Background: "l'" is the user formerly known as Vram. He decided to leave the site, and tried to remove his impact as much as possible. He deleted many of his answers (perhaps questions too, I'm not sure), and comments. He also has tried to get rid of all his rep by giving it out in bounties. Many of his posts have been undeleted, but the comments cannot be, and so some comment threads will be hard to understand.

Now if you happen to stumble upon any of this, you'll know the background.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Also, the minimum reputation required to post a bounty is 75.